# Deleting object in function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Let's say I have created two objects from class `foo` and now want to combine the two. How, if at all possible, can I accomplish that within a function like this:

```
def combine(first, second):
    first.value += second.value
    del second #this doesn't work, though first.value *does* get changed
```

instead of doing something like

```
def combine(first, second):
    first.value += second.value
```

in the function and putting `del second` immediately after the function call?

Comment: When you say, "this doesn't work", what do you mean?  It seems like there's some effect of the `del` you're expecting and not seeing.

Comment: I meant it doesn't delete the object once I exit the `combine` function

Comment: How can you know that the object was not deleted?

Comment: @Lott: I can still call its functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. All `del` does against names is unbind them. This only removes the local reference. The object will be destroyed when there are no references to it anywhere, or all the references are in a reference loop.

Comment: Objects will be destroyed between the last time you can access them and the end of the program. In CPython, most objects are immediately destroyed and cycles are periodically destroyed (except cycles of objects with `__del__` defined). Of course, there are few good reasons to use reference cycles and fewer to define `__del__`.